# Mysql syntax issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I make query and I think it correct syntax:

```
  SELECT a1.androidPackage, a1.country, a1.revenueRate as old_CPI, 
         a2.revenueRate as new_CPI 
  FROM ad_appnext a1 
  WHERE  DATE(date_created) = CURDATE() AND country = 'UK' 
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT * 
            FROM ad_appnext 
            WHERE  DATE(date_created) = '2014-04-02' AND country = 'UK') a2 
        ON a1.androidPackage = a2.androidPackage 
    WHERE a1.revenueRate != a2.revenueRate;
```

but when I run It show issue:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ad_appnext WHERE 
>   DATE(date_created) = '2014-04-02' AN' at line 1

Please help me sloved this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two WHERE clauses. You should have only one and it should come after the FROM clause.

```
SELECT a1.androidPackage, a1.country, a1.revenueRate as old_CPI, a2.revenueRate as new_CPI FROM ad_appnext a1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ad_appnext WHERE DATE(date_created) = '2014-04-02' AND country = 'UK') a2 ON a1.androidPackage = a2.androidPackage 
WHERE a1.revenueRate != a2.revenueRate"
AND DATE(date_created) = CURDATE() AND country = 'UK'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two WHERE clauses

Try this

```
SELECT a1.androidPackage, a1.country, a1.revenueRate as old_CPI, 
         a2.revenueRate as new_CPI 
  FROM ad_appnext a1 

    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT * 
            FROM ad_appnext 
            WHERE  DATE(date_created) = '2014-04-02' AND country = 'UK') a2 
        ON a1.androidPackage = a2.androidPackage 
    WHERE  DATE(date_created = CURDATE() AND country = 'UK' 
        and a1.revenueRate != a2.revenueRate;
```